# Android Detect if app is downloading

Tags: android, download, installation, apk

I know that there are similar questions on stackoverflow and i read then all. My question is little bit different. I implement some small app that with iptables and I need to know if user  install some app and this is not downloaded yet. My app must wait then until this app is installed. I know how to make an receiver for `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED` but how can I get information about apps that are installing now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting specific app info is messy: not sure you can get it. [This link](http://blog.lytsing.org/archives/135.html) provides some info about how to listen to the Download Manager app: there might be a way for you to use that and determine if what is downloading is actually an apk.

Comment: Thanks. But it would be don´t work on this way. Are there some other methods? My app is for rooted devices. Are there some methods to monitor download from market with some kind of network monitor?